# Formatting Zero Values as Empty String?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, formatting

I'm struggling with my first foray into WPF string formatting. I'd like to be able to format a textbox column in a data grid with an empty string when the underlying value is zero and format all other values as 0.000. However, my XAML doesn't seem to be up to the job as it shows blanks for *all* values and not just for zeros:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="dL" Binding="{Binding Path=Value.DLHistoric, StringFormat='{}{0.000;; }'" Width="Auto" />
```

I am using the semicolon operator as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and have added a space after the second semicolon to get the empty string.

Many thanks!

**Update**

This does the trick:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="dL" Binding="{Binding Path=Value.DLHistoric, StringFormat=0.000;;#}" Width="Auto" />
```

Comment: what happens when not in WPF? try it in a simple console program and what happens?

Comment: It's absolutely fine in a small test app. Just in WPF it seems not to work.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `{}` at the beginning?

Comment: Then it won't run, I'm afraid.

Comment: I would just go with an IValueConverter then..

Comment: Got it working. See above. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: create an answer and mark it as solved..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example IValueConverter

```
   [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
    public class StringToFeetAndInches : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string str = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;
            str = str.Insert(1, "'");
            str = str + "\"";
            return str; 
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    } 

<UserControl.Resources>
<NS:StringToFeetAndInches x:Key="cStringToFeetAndInches"/>
</UserControl.Resource> 

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource cStringToFeetAndInches}}" />
```

Comment: @Caledonian Coder you gotta check it as answered then...And gimme an upvote

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to do either. Let me check the FAQ.

Comment: OK - it says that I need to get a reputation of 15 to give an upvote. I'll return and do it when I get to that.